# Setting an XWindow "Pixel" data type in a Truecolor visual

Tags: x11

Some XWindow GUI toolkits (for example Motif) set widgets colors by using the X11 Pixel data type. For example, setting the foreground or background colors of a widget is done through the XmNforeground and XmNbackground values, which expect a Pixel data type.

However, all documentation and samples I found build the Pixel value from either an string named color (ie: "red"), or by using XAllocColorCells(), which implies a Pseudocolor visual.

I need some way of setting the XmNbackground resource from red, green, and blue values in a Truecolor visual. How can I achieve that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XAllocColor` or `XAllocNamedColor`. They work in all types of visuals.

`XAllocColorCells` is not what you need in any case. It is designed for dynamic colormaps. These allow you to cycle screen colors by changing the colormap, without updating actual screen pixels, and perform other clever tricks.